# FactoryGirl выдает ошибку ArgumentError: Factory not registered:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

При запуске теста `poll_spec.rb`, появляется ошибка:

> ArgumentError: Factory not registered: vote_option

Здесь мой код.

factories.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email "mail@mail.com"
    password "foobarrr"
    password_confirmation "foobarrr"
  end

  factory :poll do
    topic "What your name?"

    trait :vote_option1 do
      association :vote_option, title: "Dima"
    end

    trait :vote_option2 do
      association :vote_option, title: "Sasha"
    end
  end
end
```

poll_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'


RSpec.describe Poll, type: :model do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  #subject { @poll }

  #it { should respond_to(:topic) }
  #it {should be_valid}


  describe "wrong information" do
    describe "less than or equal 1 vote option" do
      before do
        FactoryGirl.create(:poll, :vote_option1)

      end

      it { should_not be_valid }
    end
  end

end
```

гем файл:

```
...........................
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.4.4'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.46.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.5.0'
end
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

По вопросу: надо объявить фабрику vote_option, либо изменить тесты.

Далее, вот здесь 
`FactoryGirl.create(:poll, :vote_option1)`
второй аргумент должен быть хэшем с параметрами, а не именем еще одной фабрики:
`FactoryGirl.create(:poll, topic: 'WTF?')`

Опять же, странное использовние трейтов, нет объединения в фабрике. Должно быть что-то типа:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email "mail@mail.com"
    password "foobarrr"
    password_confirmation "foobarrr"
  end

  factory :poll do
    topic "What your name?"

    trait :vote_option1 do
      association :vote_option, title: "Dima"
    end

    trait :vote_option2 do
      association :vote_option, title: "Sasha"
    end

    factory :poll_with_vote1, traits: [:vote_option1]
    factory :poll_with_vote2, traits: [:vote_option2]
  end
end
```

(Хотя трейты тут не нужны вообще, как по мне, но я допускаю, что есть еще какие-то новые признаки фабрик, которые потребуют группирования.)
Ну а дальше стремительно идем к успеху так:

```
describe "wrong information" do
  describe "less than or equal 1 vote option" do
    before do
      FactoryGirl.create(:poll_with_vote1)
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

Comment: Спасибо, Павел. В модели  Poll валидатор указал: validates :vote_options, presence: true Теперь при запускке теста появляется ошибка:  **ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Vote options can't be blank**. Странно, ведь фабрики имеют входные данные.

Comment: Нужно смотреть состояние БД непосредственно перед валидацией и тогда разбираться, чего именно не хватает. Можно посмотреть в коллбэках before и after прямо в самой фабрике.

ps В первом посте не помешал бы код используемых моделей.

Answer (score 0):

Вы в трейтах :vote_option1 и :vote_option2 ссылаетесь на фабрику :vote_option, которая не объявлена. Это приводит к возникновению ошибки.

```
trait :vote_option1 do
  association :vote_option, title: "Dima"
end
```